# Extract particular string value from long string pattern in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string-matching

I have string containing value as

**=Fields!EmpID.Value#*#=Fields!ChequeName.Value#*#=Fields!address.Value**

and so on with multiple values in same pattern

I have to extraxt only values like  ***EmpID,ChequeName,address*** etc  in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim errString As String 
Dim correctString As String 
Dim Newstring As String
  correctString = errString.Replace("=Fields!", "");

 Newstring = correctString.Replace(".Value##", ",");

 Newstring = Newstring .Replace(".Value", "");
```

Comment: output should be is address  It is address.value now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Dim inStr As String = "=Fields!EmpID.Value##=Fields!ChequeName.Value##=Fields!address.Value"
  Dim correctStr As String = inStr.Replace("=Fields!", "").Replace("##", ",").Replace(".Value", "")
```

**Output will be**

```
 EmpID,ChequeName,address
```